# Is there a python linter/formatter that allows and enforces leading commas?

Tags: python, formatter, linter

Is there any python linter/formatter option that allows or even enforces leading commas on lists and multi-line function arguments?

I love everything that `black` does, but anything to do with a comma deals with trailing commas or not. Even if the vast majority of creation uses commas at the end of the line, [there *are* legit reasons for using leading commas](https://dev.to/tao/the-case-for-comma-leading-lists-3n49), so I'm surprised to struggle with finding the options that provide for it.

Example:

```
FORMATTERS = {
    "field1": lambda x: f'{x} '
    , "field2": lambda x: f'{x} '
    , "field3": lambda x: f'{x} '
    , "field4": lambda x: f'{x:d} '
    , "field4 %": lambda x: f'{x:.1f} % '
    , "field5": lambda x: f'{x:d} '
    , "field5 %": lambda x: f'{x:.1f} % '
    , "field6": lambda x: f'{x:>d} '
    , "field6 %": lambda x: f'{x:>.1f} % '
    , "field7": lambda x: f'{x:d} '
    , "field7 %": lambda x: f'{x:.1f} % '
    , "field8": lambda x: f'{x:d} '
    , "field8 %": lambda x: f'{x:.1f} % '
    , "Total": lambda x: f'{x:d} '
}
```

I am asking whether there is a config option for any linter/formatter that would allow and even enforce this.

Comment: Leading comma on a line?

Comment: If you could find a Python style guide that recommends this, that could lead you to an answer.

Comment: I've edited to make it linter _or formatter_, because you mentioned black and black is a _formatter_, not a linter. Also, enforcing a certain coding style is th3 job of a formatter. That could also help you expand your search for tools and possible answers.

Comment: FWIW, `pycodestyle` has a rule E203 to detect whitespace before `,`, `;`, or `:`. Docs [here](https://pycodestyle.pycqa.org/en/latest/intro.html#error-codes) (though it's documented as only "whitespace before `:`" so I've submitted [a PR](https://github.com/PyCQA/pycodestyle/pull/1040)).